# Overlaying PictureBoxes with transparency

Tags: c#, transparency, picturebox

I am adding PictureBoxes to a panel programatically. The Panel has a background image, and the pictureboxes have png's in them which contain areas of transparency.

I had thought that to get the transparency to work, they should be added with the Parent being assigned to the last control added - So the first PB has the parent=panel, PB2's parent is PB1 etc.

These PB's are small and don't always overlap any other PB. Where they don't, I get the behaviour I want, I can see the panel background fine. Where they do overlap however, I get the following:
The first image to be placed is fine. The second image to be placed is truncated where the first image overlaps it.

I am setting the parent like this

```
if (LastIndex == 0)
        {
            thumbnail.Parent = this.BoardPanel;
        }
        else
        {
            thumbnail.Parent = this.BoardPanel.Controls[LastIndex-1];

        }
        LastIndex++;
```

The weird thing is that I can always see the background image, so the transparency is working somewhere?

Comment: Your reasoning was right but your PBs are truncated because that is what Parents __do__ to their childern/Controls: They __truncate__ them. - In Winforms there is __no__ working tranparency for __overlapping__ controls, only __faked__ transparency for __nested__ controls. Period. . If you need it you need to rethink your program. Maybe use WPF? (LOL) Maybe draw the PBs' images onto the Panel or its BackgroundImage -

Comment: "the pictureboxes have png's in them which contain areas of transparency"  Depending on the complexity of your images, you may be able to literally make those transparent areas **not exist** in the PictureBoxes by setting up GraphicPath(s) and creating a Region() with those areas removed (this will give you **non-rectangular** controls).  Then you would actually see the underlying Panel and/or PictureBoxes thru the holes.  At any rate, the Parent for all the PBs should be the Panel.